# PHP - Replace various case types in string with hyperlink and retain original case

Tags: php

I have the following string:

"This is my string with three instances of MYTEXT. That was the first instance. This is the second instance of Mytext. And this is the third instance of mytext."

I need to replace each instance of Mytext (all three instances) with a version wrapped in a tag, so I want to wrap HTML tags around each instance. This is easy enough and I have no problem doing this. My question is - how do I do this while retaining the original case of each instance. The output I need is:

"This is my string with three instances of MYTEXT. That was the first instance. This is the second instance of Mytext. And this is the third instance of mytext."

I've been looking at str_ireplace and preg_teplace but none of them seem to do the job.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use backreferences to accomplish this:

```
preg_replace('/mytext/i', '<a href="foo.html">\\0</a>', $str);
```

The `\\0` backreference in the replacement string will be replaced with the entire match, effectively maintaining the original case.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, and far more inefficient solution that uses the basics.

```
<?php

    $string = "This is my string with three instances of MYTEXT. That was the first instance. This is the second instance of Mytext. And this is the third instance of mytext.";
    $copyOfString = $string; // A copy of the original string, so that you can use the original string later.

    $matches = array(); // An array to fill with the matches returned by the PHP function using Regular Expressions.
    preg_match_all("/mytext/i", $string, $matches); // The above-mentioned function. Note that the 'i' makes the search case-insensitive.

    foreach($matches as $matchSubArray){ 
        foreach($matchSubArray as $match){ // This is only one way to do this.
            $replacingString = "<b>".$match."</b>"; // Edit to use the tags you want to use.
            $copyOfString = str_replace($match, $replacingString, $copyOfString); // str_replace is case-sensitive.
        }
    }

    echo $copyOfString; // Output the final, and modified string.

?>
```

NOTE: As I hinted at in the beginning, this approach uses bad programming practice.